# SpringBoot2 @DateTimeFormat annotation with LocalDateTime doesn't work as i expected

Tags: java

i want to convert `LocalDateTime` to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` format with `@DateTimeFormat`.

following is my source code.

- Entity Class

```java
@Entity // JPA Annotation
@Setter // Lombok Annotations
@Getter
public class CustomModel {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime addDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime lastModifyDate;
}
```

- Controller Class

```java
...
CustomModel customModel = new CustomModel();
customModel.setAddDate(LocalDateTime.now());
customModel.setLastModifyDate(LocalDateTime.now());
...
```

and following is result.

[image: wrong date time format in db]

In above image, i expected '2019-08-11 03:08:56'.

But result format is '2019-08-11 03:08:56.814944'.

what is wrong??

Comment: Could you please share the column type you are using for this add_date column in your database?

Comment: Wehere is the problem?? (There is no single string (except format pattern) in your post (code))

Comment: its about database column type, what is your add_date type and which database using?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put the thymeleaf template, but the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation will only be taken into account if you use double bracket rather than simple bracket, i.e. `${{model.addDate}}` rather than `${model.addDate}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTimeFormatter class. But to convert, you need String representation of your date. Then parse it.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

customModel.setAddDate(LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)), formatter);
customModel.setLastModifyDate(LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)), formatter);
```